# Symfony2 get nested database data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello guys i know how this work whitout using sf2 and doctrine, but anyone can show me example how can i do this using sf2 and doctrine. Am litle confused and no have idea how to do this using lft and rgt columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle), which provides Symfony integration with the Doctrine behavioral extensions. The extension you need is the [Tree extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) which supports multiple tree strategies like nested set, closure table and materialized path.

Comment: I install SF Stof bundle but how can i install Doctrine extension ?

Comment: The Doctrine extensions are required Composer dependencies of this bundle, which functions as the glue between the extensions and the Symfony framework. They are automatically loaded when installing/configuring this bundle.